# Pydrive can't open .csv file : No downloadLink/exportLinks for mimetype found in metadata

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, pydrive

I just starting using Google Colab and it looks really promising (free GPU yes please!), but I haven't been able to even import data from my drive. I followed the tutorial for using Pydrive but keep getting the error

**FileNotDownloadableError: No downloadLink/exportLinks for mimetype found in metadata**

when trying to run the following code

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy.misc # to visualize only  
import pandas as pd
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

#2. Get the file
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'1SinPTGxX_MbXWTrB5vcmfXKttRZnDfYa'}) # replace the id with id of file you want to access

downloaded.GetContentFile("train_x.csv",  mimetype=None)
downloaded.GetContentFile("train_y.csv",  mimetype=None)

x = np.loadtxt('train_x.csv', delimiter=",")
y = np.loadtxt('train_y.csv', delimiter=",")

print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
```

there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155300/pydrive-error-no-downloadlink-exportlinks-for-mimetype-found-in-metadata) asked before but I don't understand how they solved the issue (I think it's just setting mimetype=None but that didn't work, neither did setting it to mimetype='text/csv').

I also tried importing the data from google spreadsheets, but because the dataset is pretty large (2GB) it keeps giving me an error when I try to convert it to a spreadsheet.

My last option is to host it on Github or something, but I'd still like to know why it's not working. Thanks!

Comment: Is your fileID a folder or a file?

Comment: The fileID is a folder

Comment: Try downloading each file individually using the recipe for files here: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=zU5b6dlRwUQk

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get the file ID of your **original file**. Not the one that can be opened in Google Drive (bc this change the format).
The ID can be obtained by pretending to share your file. Then, you will get a link such as https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HbEfAPN7nQVCXbvspwWayOSU7oPr/view?usp=sharing. Copy the long strange string between "d/" and "/view?".
Your code should work then.